# How can I use melt() to reshape a pandas DataFrame to a list, creating an index from a crosstab column and creating a new variable in its place?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a matrix of data 29523 rows x 503 cols of which 3 cols are indices (below is a subset for example).

```
IDX1|  IDX2  | IDX3 | 1983 Q4   |  X  | Y |  Z  |1984 Q1 |   X  | Y | Z 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
A   |   A1   |  Q   |   10      |  A  | F | NaN | 110    |   A  | F | NaN
A   |   A2   |  Q   |   20      |  B  | C | 40  | 120    |   B  | C | 240
A   |   A3   |  Q   |   30      |  A  | F | NaN | 130    |   A  | F | NaN
A   |   A4   |  Q   |   40      |  B  | C | 80  | 140    |   B  | C | 280
A   |   A5   |  Q   |   50      |  A  | F | NaN | 150    |   A  | F | NaN
A   |   A6   |  Q   |   60      |  B  | F | 120 | 160    |   B  | F | 320
```

I read this into a `DataFrame` with:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(C:\filename.csv, low_memory=False, mangle_dupe_cols=False)
```

and then use `pandas.melt()` to pivot the data:

```
df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['IDX1', 'IDX2', 'IDX3'], var_name='ValueType',
              value_name = 'Value')
```

I have also tried `stack()` but `melt()` proved better here.

```
IDX1    |   IDX2    |   IDX3    |   ValueType   |   Value
---------------------------------------------------------------
A       |   A1      |   Q       |   1983 Q4     |   10
A       |   A1      |   Q       |   X           |   A
A       |   A1      |   Q       |   Y           |   F
A       |   A1      |   Q       |   Z           |   NaN
A       |   A1      |   Q       |   1984 Q1     |   110
A       |   A1      |   Q       |   X           |   A
A       |   A1      |   Q       |   Y           |   F
A       |   A1      |   Q       |   Z           |   NaN
A       |   A2      |   Q       |   1983 Q4     |   20
A       |   A2      |   Q       |   X           |   B
A       |   A2      |   Q       |   Y           |   C
A       |   A2      |   Q       |   Z           |   40
```

The option `mangle_dupe_cols` on the `read_csv` if `True` will place a `.int` suffix against all `ValueType`s that are duplicated. This is not ideal, but without it there is no way of linking the values for the variables to the correct period.

What I would prefer to do is instead of having the `Period` `(1984 Q1)` as a `ValueType`, give the `Period`s corresponding `Value` a variable `'W'` and have each period form part of the `IDX` as below:

```
IDX1    |   IDX2    |   IDX3 | IDX4    |    ValueType   |   Value
---------------------------------------------------------------
A       |   A1      |   Q    |  1983 Q4|    W           |   10
A       |   A1      |   Q    |  1983 Q4|    X           |   A
A       |   A1      |   Q    |  1983 Q4|    Y           |   F
A       |   A1      |   Q    |  1983 Q4|    Z           |   NaN
A       |   A1      |   Q    |  1984 Q1|    W           |   110
A       |   A1      |   Q    |  1984 Q1|    X           |   A
A       |   A1      |   Q    |  1984 Q1|    Y           |   F
A       |   A1      |   Q    |  1984 Q1|    Z           |   NaN
A       |   A2      |   Q    |  1983 Q4|    W           |   20
A       |   A2      |   Q    |  1983 Q4|    X           |   B
A       |   A2      |   Q    |  1983 Q4|    Y           |   C
A       |   A2      |   Q    |  1983 Q4|    Z           |   40
```

Is the above possible with pandas or numpy?

My final `DataFrame` is going to be 14,761,500 rows x 6 cols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
In [189]: df
Out[189]: 
  IDX1 IDX2 IDX3  1983 Q4  X  Y    Z  1984 Q1 X.1 Y.1  Z.1
0    A   A1    Q       10  A  F  NaN      110   A   F  NaN
1    A   A2    Q       20  B  C   40      120   B   C  240
2    A   A3    Q       30  A  F  NaN      130   A   F  NaN
3    A   A4    Q       40  B  C   80      140   B   C  280
4    A   A5    Q       50  A  F  NaN      150   A   F  NaN
5    A   A6    Q       60  B  F  120      160   B   F  320
```

Let us first set `['IDX1', 'IDX2', 'IDX3']` as the index.

```
df = df.set_index(['IDX1', 'IDX2', 'IDX3'])
```

The other columns have a periodic quality to them; we *want to handle every 4
columns as a group*. This idea of "handling as a group" leads naturally to
assigning a new index level to the column index; some value which is the same
for every 4 columns. This would be ideal:

```
               1983 Q4            1984 Q1           
                     W  X  Y    Z       W  X  Y    Z
IDX1 IDX2 IDX3                                      
A    A1   Q         10  A  F  NaN     110  A  F  NaN
     A2   Q         20  B  C  240     120  B  C  240
     A3   Q         30  A  F  NaN     130  A  F  NaN
     A4   Q         40  B  C  280     140  B  C  280
     A5   Q         50  A  F  NaN     150  A  F  NaN
     A6   Q         60  B  F  320     160  B  F  320
```

We can achieve this by building a MultiIndex and assigning it to `df.columns`:

```
columns = [col for col in df.columns if col[0] not in set(list('XYZ'))]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([columns, list('WXYZ')])
```

Now the desired long-format DataFrame can be obtained by calling `df.stack` to
move the column levels into the row index:

```
df.columns.names = ['IDX4', 'ValueType']
series = df.stack(['IDX4', 'ValueType'], dropna=False)
```

---

Note also that when `mangle_dupe_cols=False`, the duplicate columns, `X`, `Y`,
`Z`, **get overwritten**. So you lose data with `mangle_dupe_cols=False`. For
example, when you use `mangle_dupe_cols=False` the last row's `Z` value gets
assigns to every `Z` column regardless of the period.

So we must use `mangle_dupe_cols=True`, (or just leave it out since that is the
default) and adjust the code accordingly.  That, fortunately, is not hard to do
since we are reassigning `df.columns` to a custom-build MultiIndex anyway.

---

Putting it all together:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('data', sep=r'\s*[|]\s*')
df = df.set_index(['IDX1', 'IDX2', 'IDX3'])
columns = [col for col in df.columns if col[0] not in set(list('XYZ'))]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([columns, list('WXYZ')])
df.columns.names = ['IDX4', 'ValueType']
series = df.stack(['IDX4', 'ValueType'], dropna=False)
print(series.head())
```

yields

```
IDX1  IDX2  IDX3  IDX4     ValueType
A     A1    Q     1983 Q4  W             10
                           X              A
                           Y              F
                           Z            NaN
                  1984 Q1  W            110
dtype: object
```

Note that since we've removed all the column levels, the result is a Series. 
If you want a DataFrame with 6 columns, then we should follow it up with:

```
series.name = 'Value'
df = series.reset_index()
print(df.head())
```

which yields

```
  IDX1 IDX2 IDX3     IDX4 ValueType Value
0    A   A1    Q  1983 Q4         W    10
1    A   A1    Q  1983 Q4         X     A
2    A   A1    Q  1983 Q4         Y     F
3    A   A1    Q  1983 Q4         Z   NaN
4    A   A1    Q  1984 Q1         W   110
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the format is now correct but there is an issue with the values in each of the groups.   My dataset runs from 1983 Q4 to 2014 Q4 and for each group I have 4 values (W,X,Y,Z). These also repeat in each group and can also be NaN.   It appears that the proposed solution excludes NaNs and also gets confused when allocating Values to the correct ValueType and Period combination.  The example data I provided should have had a few more Period Groups.  The last value in the row of the initial df is being written to all places where there are NaNs

Comment: We can prevent the NaNs from being dropped by passing `dropna=False` to the call to `df.stack`. The misallocation of Values is due to `mangle_dupe_cols=False`. Not only are the column names duplicated, but the column values are too. Thanks for pointing that out; I didn't realize that was the behavior when using this parameter. I've changed the code above to address both issues.