# How can I round values in Pandas DataFrame containing mixed datatypes for further data comparison?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe df_left:

```
  IDX1 IDX2 IDX3     IDX4 ValueType Value
0    A   A1    Q  1983 Q4         W    10.123
1    A   A1    Q  1983 Q4         X     A
2    A   A1    Q  1983 Q4         Y     F
3    A   A1    Q  1983 Q4         Z   NaN
4    A   A1    Q  1984 Q1         W   110.456
...
```

created from a previous post:

[Background information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941384/how-can-i-use-melt-to-reshape-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-list-creating-an-index)

AND dataframe df_right:

```
  IDX1 IDX2 IDX3     IDX4 ValueType Value
0    A   A1    Q  1983 Q4         W    10
1    A   A1    Q  1983 Q4         X     A
2    A   A1    Q  1983 Q4         Y     F
3    A   A1    Q  1983 Q4         Z   NaN
4    A   A1    Q  1984 Q1         W   110
```

I compare and reconcile the data both values and text of which the following works:

```
df_compare = pd.merge(df_Left, df_Right, how ='outer', on = ['IDX1', 'IDX2', 'IDX3', 'IDX4', 'ValueType'])
df_compare.columns = ['IDX1', 'IDX2', 'IDX3', 'IDX4', 'ValueType', 'From', 'To']
df_compare = df_compare[df_compare.From!=df_compare.To]
```

Whilst the results are as expected, before the comparison I would like to round the data in the value coulmn.

I have tried:

```
df.apply(np.round)
```

and also:

```
df.round(decimals=0, out=None)
```

but both as expected thow an error:

`AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'rint'", u'occurred at index Code')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom method for rounding just the floats may solve rounding a mixed dtype column

```
In [238]: def round_float(s):
    '''1. if s is float, round it to 0 decimals
       2. else return s as is
    '''
    import re
    m = re.match("(\d+\.\d+)",s.__str__())
    try:
        r = round(float(m.groups(0)[0]),0)
    except:
        r = s
    return r

In [239]: s = u'''  IDX1 IDX2 IDX3     IDX4 ValueType Value
0    A   A1    Q  1983 Q4         W    10.23
1    A   A1    Q  1983 Q4         X     A
2    A   A1    Q  1983 Q4         Y     F
3    A   A1    Q  1983 Q4         Z   NaN
4    A   A1    Q  1984 Q1         W   110.15'''

In [240]: df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), delimiter="\s+")

In [241]: df1["Value2"] = df1.Value.apply(round_float)

In [242]: df1
Out[242]:
    IDX1 IDX2  IDX3 IDX4 ValueType   Value Value2
0 A   A1    Q  1983   Q4         W   10.23     10
1 A   A1    Q  1983   Q4         X       A      A
2 A   A1    Q  1983   Q4         Y       F      F
3 A   A1    Q  1983   Q4         Z     NaN    NaN
4 A   A1    Q  1984   Q1         W  110.15    110
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a fairly general solution you can apply to multiple columns.  The 'To' column doesn't need to be rounded, I just included it for the generality of two columns rather than one:

```
df

  IDX1 IDX2  IDX3 IDX4 ValueType     From   To
0   A1    Q  1983   Q4         W   10.123   10
3   A1    Q  1983   Q4         Z      NaN  NaN
4   A1    Q  1984   Q1         W  110.456  110

In [399]: df[['From','To']].astype(float).apply(np.round)

   From   To
0    10   10
3   NaN  NaN
4   110  110
```

That's the safest way in that it won't let you accidentally wipe out non-numeric values, but if you have truly mixed types in there, you can do this:

```
df[['From','To']].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).apply(np.round)

   From   To
0    10   10
3   NaN  NaN
4   110  110
```

But since this will convert any non-numeric values to NaN, just make sure that's what you want before you over-write anything.

Comment: Thanks. I still seem to be getting decimals
`df_compare[['From','To']].astype(float).apply(np.round)
df_compare['Result'] = pd.Series(df_compare.From.astype(float).apply(np.round)
df_compare.To.astype(float).apply(np.round), index=df_compare.index)`

`df_compare = df_compare.query('Result != 0') `

Comment: Can you show the data/values for which this happens?  I just used the data/code you provided and didn't see this.  Also, you may want to add this to the question rather than as a comment so it's easier to read.

Comment: I can't quite tell what you are doing in the comment, but you don't need the `Series`, you can just store result like this:  `df_compare['Result'] = df_compare.From.astype(float).apply(np.round)`